# MVC Model binding auto generated id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model-binding

I have a issue with values not being bound to an object in MVC.

I have a Controller class

```
public class AddOrderController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailsRepository _orderdetailsrepository;
    public OrderDetailsModel Orderdetails { get; }

    public AddOrderController(IOrderDetailsRepository orderrepository)
    {
        _orderdetailsrepository = orderrepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        AddOrderModel addorder = new AddOrderModel();
        return View(addorder);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(AddOrderModel order) 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And the Index Returns and AddOrderModel object form the From in the View:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="AddOrder" asp-action="Index" role="form">
<div>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <label asp-for="@Model.Quantity"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Quantity" />
            </tr>
        <tr>
                @{

                var orderId = (orderdetails.GetOrdersIDAsync().Result.Max() +1);

                <label asp-for="@Model.OrderId" ></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.OrderId" value="@orderId" disabled="disabled" />
                }
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</br>

<div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Add order"></input> 
</div>
```

The issue is with the OrderID

I am expecting that the returned AddOrderModel object is corrctly mapped. While debuging the Model.Quantity is passed correctly to the IActionResult but the OrderId is not. The OrderId is generated and only displayed to the user.

My model class:

```
public class AddOrderModel
{
    
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public short Quantity { get; set; }

    public float Discount { get; set; }

}
```

And I can't figure out what the issue here is.

Comment: It is because your orderid field his marked as disabled so it is never posted to the server.

Comment: Okay so how to make it as EE can't enter a value and display it to the user?

Comment: Display as plain text to the user and put the actual value as hidden field on form.